# map an array and call async fonction inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, web-scraping

What's the way to map an array and call an async function with all items?

```js
const scrape = async (url) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="page-body"]/h2/a');
    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();

    //here do an another thing with an other function
    const obj = formatRes(rawTxt);


    browser.close();
    
    return obj; 
};
```

the second function :

```js
const formatRes = (res) => {
    [...]
    return obj;
}
```

call the first function :

```js
linksB.map(item => scrape(item));
```

`linksB` is an array of URLs.

I want to put all the returned object from scrape in a new array.

Comment: `Promise.all`…?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have an array of links where you want to make a request to each one, then we can do array `map` inside of `Promise.all`

```js
const urls = [ 'url1...', 'url2...', 'url3...' ];

const responses = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => makeRequest(url)))

// use responses array where each response map exactly to each url's response
```

Comment: thanks, but I have an error : `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` on the `await Promise...`

Comment: you need to wrap that code inside an `async function(){ ... code .... }` and when you use that function consider using `.then` on it or `await` in front of it

Comment: I'm sorry, I have try to wrap `const reponses = await... ` into `async function(){...} ` but still not working